# How to find the Fastest DNS servers to host our domain?

Tags: dns, performance, dns-servers

The question was born because lately we've seen a pretty odd (well, at least for us, for the first time) - error message in Google webmaster tools - "**DNS lookup timeout**" ... I was pretty sure that with eNom's 5 DNS servers (dns1... to dns5.name-services.com) we're pretty set...

But it appears that from (Europe/Hungary), for example - dns1.name-services.com takes 170ms. to respond on a ping... while GoDaddy's ns75.domaincontrol.com - takes only 40 ms. to respond... and at the same time - dns2 to dns5.name-services.com - each result with a timeout error (on ping)...

This issue came to our attention right in the final stages of optimizing our web-site (almost to death) - basically, just in time...

**I would love to move our domains to a fast (fastest?) and reliable DNS server.. - but how do I find one ?**

Also - I did the ping tests from various geographic locations (we have servers in many countries) and GoDaddy seemed to be faster than eNom almost in every case.

I'd be very thankful for any hints on this!

Edited: Well.. maybe this one does not have an answer, after all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at Amazon Route53: http://aws.amazon.com/en/route53/
These are distributed DNS servers over the whole world which should hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: Hey, that's a nice one... thank you! I guess your answer is better than anything I was hoping to get on this question.